# formatting section numbers with \hangsection in Memoir

Tags: sectioning, formatting, memoir

I'd previously been renewing my section command in Memoir in order to style the section numbers by prefacing them with a symbol (§) and following them with a period:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{§ \arabic{section}.}
```

Werner has helpfully indicated in [another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61182/section-text-without-heading-following-section-number-on-same-line-in-memoir) a way of putting the section numbers in the margin, getting rid of headings, and having the text body begin from the section numbers without any skip:

```
\hangsecnum
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hangsection}{%
  \savebox{\@tempboxa}{\normalfont\ }%
  \section{}\hspace*{-\wd\@tempboxa}%
}
\makeatother
\setaftersecskip{0pt}%
```

Could anyone indicate how to format the section numbers (e.g., with a symbol and a period) with such a new command?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can modify the section number formatting function `\setsecnumformat`:

```
\setsecnumformat{\llap{\S\@nameuse{the#1}.\ }}
```

Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\hangsecnum
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\makeatletter
\setsecnumformat{\llap{\S\@nameuse{the#1}.\ }}
\newcommand{\hangsection}{%
  \savebox{\@tempboxa}{\normalfont\ }%
  \section{}\hspace*{-\wd\@tempboxa}%
}
\makeatother
\setaftersecskip{0pt}%
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\hangsection\lipsum[1]
\hangsection\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

With XeLaTeX, you can use `§` instead of `\S`.